# Why are unit tests necessary?

Tags: java, unit-testing

This may not be the right place to ask this. However, I was just hired a couple of months ago at my first programming job as a student developer for my university, and I have had to write a couple of unit tests already. Before I was hired, I had the opportunity to talk to another developer who made the case unit tests were not necessary. He made the case: if you throw data at a method should know what comes out without writing a test, which I think makes sense.

For example (Java):

```
public int Add(int num1, int num2) {
   return(num1 + num2);
}
//if I call Add(2,2) I know I should get 4, 
//if I call Add(5,6) I know I should get 11,
//etc...
```

I tried asking my co-worker about this and his response was more or less along the lines of, everyone else does it so we have to.

So, I guess my question is: Why are unit tests necessary if you can just test your code by calling it repeatedly with dummy data rather than testing it once with a unit test?

Comment: There will be many possible paths to answer this, but I think the most important one is: writing unit tests for your code will make you understand the code you are writing much better and thus discover potential weaknesses and potentials for improvement.

Comment: That argument, at least as presented here, makes no sense as an objection to unit tests. If you know what you expect out given those inputs, why *not* express that expectation in a way that can automatically be verified? *"you can just test your code by calling it repeatedly with dummy data"* - that sounds quite a lot like unit testing...

Comment: Major benefits of UT IMO: 1 check the code does (only) what it's supposed to do now 2 check the code still does what it's supposed to do in the future 3 put yourself in the feet of a consumer of your code and detect design issues 4 provide some kind of additional documentation for those wanting to understand the code. To be honest if a dev tells me UTs are not necessary during an interview: game over (never happened).

Comment: Unit testing is automated sanity testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A unit test is a specific written test in an easy to manage and run framework that works by calling your code with "dummy data".  Of course, a good test will also hit all sorts of edge cases as well.

Just for fun, let's take your code:

What happens if I pass it `INT_MAX` (not sure of Java equivalent of this, but perhaps `Integer.MAX_VALUE`) as `num1` and say 10 as `num2` into your code.  Will it return `INT_MAX + 10` or something else?  If it does so, is that an error condition or expected?  A unit test can formalize these questions as well.